# Edit does not save function in newly updated R 3.2.2

Tags: r, rstudio, edit

The more formal operator saves the changes to the function:

```
function_I_want_to_edit <- edit()
```

This opens the editing window and I can make changes which are there when I re-open it.

However, if I simply try:

```
edit(function_I_want_to_edit)
```

It opens the editing window but it does not appear to have saved my changes when I re-open it. This is in RStudio, newly updated to Version 3.2.2.

I can't tell if it always worked like this or not, because I believe I was able to change one thing, and then it stopped working.

Has anyone noticed a similar problem with `edit` or `fix`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be the intended behavior. If you look at the help for `edit`:

> It is important to realize that `edit` does not change the object called
>   `name`. Instead, a copy of `name` is made and it is that copy which is
>   changed. Should you want the changes to apply to the object `name` you
>   must assign the result of `edit` to `name`. (Try `fix` if you want to make
>   permanent changes to an object.)

`fix` does save the changes I make to a function.